# New facebook panel: can't put app in production mode event after setting a notification email

Tags: facebook

Despite having set a notification emai, the button for enabling the facebook App in production mode is still disabled.

[image]
[image]

Comment: First of all, next time please set your FB language to English before making such screenshots - that makes them much easier readable to most people here.

Comment: The email address needs to be verified - is that the case? (I am not sure if it has to be long to one of the developer accounts as well at the moment.)

Comment: The email account belongs to the client, he told me he confirmed the email. Edited with english screenshots. I can't even test it with my email account, since I'm not the administrator of the app, just a developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email you have to set is on the basic info section.

[image]

Failed to see this field at first sight since it seems only the app administrator can edit it.